# why thymeleaf tag th:text doesn't print?

Tags: html, eclipse, thymeleaf

in MemberPage.html i have a tag th:text="${username}", but it doesn't display the value when i run the page on the server, why?

MemberPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>HOME</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:text="${username}"></div>
```

The Controller

```
String username = "Username";
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("username",username);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("MemberPage.html");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Is your project properly set up to use Thymeleaf at runtime? You haven't given details on why this should work.

Comment: How can i check that? btw i'm using eclipse and i've already imported the thymeleaf library and the relative plugin

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code
from:

```
<div th:text="${username}"></div>
```

to:

```
<div th:text="${session.username}"></div>
```

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't work